# have a javascript src dynamically changed by php session

Tags: php, javascript

I have been looking at SO posts for hours trying to figure this out.  I would like to be able to change my src in a js script using a dynamically created session variable.

```
$source = $_SESSION['amz'];echo $source;
```

echo's mws like it is supposed to. Now I am trying to get it into my script:

```
$a = ?><script type="text/javascript" src="buyback'<?php  echo $source; ?>'.js"></script>
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /chroot/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/buyback/buybackmws.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is the $a line.
Is this the correct start at least?  Am I just missing something very basic??  I do have session_start() at the beginning of the page.

EDIT: I pass $a into the header of the html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery_idleTimeout.js"></script>
<?php echo $a; ?>
```

Comment: What is the `$a = ?>` part for? Why not just `?>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this-

`echo $a = "<script type='text/javascript' src='buyback$source.js'></script>";`

Comment: then echo it of course

Comment: I still get the same error message.

Comment: What error you are getting onow @Jim

Comment: Same as before, unexpected ;

Comment: @Jim.. it should work. check previous line to this, it must have ";" @ the end?

Comment: I missed the trailing ;!  Thanks works great now.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
?><script type="text/javascript" src="buyback'<?php  echo $source; ?>'.js"></script>
```

the $a = is messing things up